# Better way to execute useEffect when boolean changes in one direction?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to execute effect when `val` goes from `false` to `true`, but not the other way around.

This is the best I came up with:

```
 const valPrev = useRef(val);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (val && !valPrev.current) {
      // do stuff
    }
    valPrev.current = val;
  }, [val]);
```

But it feels like there might be a more clever way, maybe using return function somehow?

Edit: my bad, I've neglected to stress, I want effect run on **change**. Whenever val **goes** from `false` to `true`. Which means it should skip the initial render.

Comment: what is the initial value of `val`?

Comment: Doesn't matter, really, but let's say `true`.

Answer (score 3):

And what about this?

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (val) {
    // do stuff
   }
}, [val]);
```

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I clarified my question.

Comment: Is there not an issue when the "do stuff" includes a function that might change between renders? If the function changes, then it'll trigger the useEffect, and the boolean might not have changed, but the "do stuff" will still run.